# WordPress comment_reply_link -- How to append a function name to the exsisting onclick value?

Tags: wordpress, onclick

I've seen many posts explaining how to add a class to this link, but they don't seem to relate to what I'm trying to accomplish. The following is the php code that renders the link...

```
comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'])));
```

The output looks something like this...

```
[a class="comment-reply-link" href="http://mysite/post-name-sug/?replytocom=23#respond" onclick="return addComment.moveForm( "comment-23", "23", "respond", "229" )"] Reply [/a]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to add some text just before closing quote of the onclick statement.

```
onclick="return addComment.moveForm( "comment-23", "23", "respond", "229" ) **myFunction**"
```

Comment: if you wants to call a function onclick, just add a class and use $('.class_name').click(function(){}); @ManthanDave